# C - fgets hangs when array not filled

Tags: c, fgets

I am taking input from `stdin` with `fgets()` and seem to have a bit of trouble with buffer overflow. I've added in a while loop which is meant to eat all characters, however my code is running multiple times and should only run once.

```
void play_game(void) {
    int ch; /* Waste */
    /* Max input from fgets */
    char c[8];

    enum cell_contents board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];

    init_board(board);

    while(!is_game_over(board)) {
        display_board(board);

        printf("Please enter a move [enter Q or ctrl-D to quit]: ");

        if(fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin)) {
            printf("Entered: %s\n", c);
            struct move calculated_move = calculate_move(c);

            if(is_valid_move(calculated_move, board))
                player_move(calculated_move, board);
            else
                printf("That is an invalid move!\n");
        }

        /* eat excess data */
        if (strlen(c) == sizeof(c)-1)
            while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

        /* eat overfilled data */
        //read_rest_of_line();

    }

    printf("Game over!\n");
    game_over(board);
}
```

Here's my results:

```
Please enter a move [enter Q or ctrl-D to quit]: E4, C4 gfgfd oigjdfogkf dohdfkho dk
Entered: E4, C4 
            +---+---+---+        
1           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
2           | o | o | o |        
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3   | o | o | o | o | o | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4   | o | . | o | . | . | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5   | o | o | o | o | o | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---++---+---+
6           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
7           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
Please enter a move [enter Q or ctrl-D to quit]: Entered: gfgfd o
That is an invalid move!
            +---+---+---+        
1           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
2           | o | o | o |        
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3   | o | o | o | o | o | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4   | o | . | o | . | . | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5   | o | o | o | o | o | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---++---+---+
6           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
7           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
Please enter a move [enter Q or ctrl-D to quit]: Entered: igjdfog
That is an invalid move!
            +---+---+---+        
1           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
2           | o | o | o |        
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3   | o | o | o | o | o | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4   | o | . | o | . | . | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5   | o | o | o | o | o | o | o |
    +---+---+---+---+---++---+---+
6           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
7           | o | o | o |        
            +---+---+---+        
      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
Please enter a move [enter Q or ctrl-D to quit]:
```

Comment: The [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) will not write beyond the end of the buffer, provided you give it a correct size. It can, however, add the newline if it fits in the buffer.

Comment: As for your problem, try to step through the code in a debugger, line by line, while keeping an eye on the variables and their contents. It might help you find out what the problem is.

Comment: Also, be careful with that loop to eat up remaining characters. What if the user entered 6 characters and a newline? Then `strlen(c) == sizeof(c) - 1` would be true as well, and you will start reading characters from the *next* line (or rather, the game would seem to lock up while `fgetc` waits for input). A better check would be if the last character in the buffer is a newline or not.

Comment: What happens if you remove the loop that consumes _the remaining characters_ from `stdin`?

Comment: How would I go about this Joachim ?

Comment: iharob, the while loop still continues looping. The problem I'm having is, I want "B4 D4" to be a valid input, as well as "B4, D4". I've given enough character space for the "B4, D4" which trigers the fgetc to clear the buffer and works perfectly. The problem I face is when I run that buffer overflow "eating" loop, the program halts until I enter another new line.

Comment: Because the newline ends this `while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` loop, remove it, it's not needed.

Comment: How do I go about preventing my input loop from triggering from buffer overflow then ?

Comment: What buffer overflow? `if(fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin))` prevents that. Perhaps your game function `calculate_move()` is doing something with `c[]` which it shouldn't.

Comment: Solved my problem: `if (strlen(c) == sizeof(c)-1 || c[sizeof(c)-1] != '\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by checking the last character in the array if it was a new line or not.

```
/* eat excess data */
if (strlen(c) == sizeof(c)-1 || c[sizeof(c)-1] != '\n')
    read_rest_of_line();

void read_rest_of_line(void){
    int ch;
    /* remove all characters from the buffer */
    while (ch = getc(stdin), ch != '\n' && ch != EOF);

    /* clear the error status of the input pointer */
    clearerr(stdin);
}
```